# On the Number of Prime Numbers less than a Given Quantity - how is the Gamma function set in relation to the Pi function?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, gamma-function, riemann-zeta

I'm trying to understand Riemann's "Über die Anzahl der Primzahlen unter einer gegebenen Größe" ("On the Number of Prime Numbers less than
a Given Quantity" in english). [Here](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/%C3%9Cber_die_Anzahl_der_Primzahlen_unter_einer_gegebenen_Gr%C3%B6%C3%9Fe) is the original work in German and [here](https://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/ezeta.pdf) the english translation.

I'm stuck right on page 1 already at this identity:

$
\int_0^\infty e^{-nx}x^{s-1}dx = \frac{\Pi(s-1)}{n^s}
$

I understand that the left side (without the "n"):

$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{s-1}dx
$

is the Gamma function and the right hand side (without the denominator):

$
\Pi(s-1)
$

is the Pi function - so the Gamma function when offset to coincide with the factorial.

For the gamma function holds:

$
\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!
$

and for the Pi function holds:

$
\Pi(n) = n!
$

and thus

$
\Pi(n-1) = (n-1)!
$

which means that:

$
\Gamma(n) = \Pi(n-1)
$

Which means I can write this also down like that:

$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{s-1}dx = \Pi(s-1)
$

which is close to the original identity from above.

But where does the "n" come from on both sides?

I don't understand how I get from

$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{s-1}dx = \Pi(s-1)
$

to

$
\int_0^\infty e^{-nx}x^{s-1}dx = \frac{\Pi(s-1)}{n^s}
$

And what does the "n" mean in this context? It's neither an argument to the function nor is it the variable which we are integrating with respect to.

Comment: Substitute $y=nx$ to get $n^{-s}\int_0^\infty e^{-y}y^{s-1}dy$.

Comment: But why would you do that in the first place? What's the meaning of n here?

Comment: It's just an identity. It works for any positive $n$. He uses that to obtain the next equation by applying the identity to each of the terms of $\zeta(s)$ and summing up the $e^{-nx}$.

Comment: You could say that the $1/n^s$ used there is one of the terms of $\zeta(s) = \sum 1/n^s$, because that's where he uses the identity. But it's kind of like asking what's the meaning of $n$ in the identity $n^{-1} = 1/n$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: That does help a lot, thanks. But he doesn't proof that this identity is actually true. Is this left as an exercise to the reader or is this a well-known identity? If yes, does this identity have a name? Or is this just trivial to see for a mathematician and that's why he doesn't bother to explain it?

Comment: It's just trivial for a mathematician. Articles like that tend to be very concise and are hard to follow through if you're not already familiar with the subject.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate it.